# Google Maps Fragment "<fragment> Pick preview layout from the Fragment Layout context menu"

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to use google maps in my app.. but when I add the map fragment I get in the Graphical Layout: " Pick preview layout from the Fragment Layout context menu".

I use the xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.tie.android.restautanta.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tie.android.restautanta"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="KEY" />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

and I added the jar file `google-play-services.jar`, And google-play-services_lib

So.. Any Idea ?

Comment: not sure what the issue is here, just that you cannot see the preview in the designer?

Comment: why do you need it, the preview is just that a preview and serves no purpose. I dont think google maps has a preview, just run your app to see what it looks like

Comment: You can follow this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm to set up your map, and download code here:https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-android for example

Answer (score 1):

I tried in Eclipse : right click on your fragment name  from "Outline" => Fragment Layout => select your fragment name.
good luck. :)